# A question about to isomorphic of two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

(A) Show that $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)^\times$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z)^\times$

(B) $(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^\times$ is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z)^\times$.

For (A) since these groups are cyclic hence isomorphic exist between these groups

Am I  right?

I don't have idea about (B)

Comment: What is $x$?${}{}$  Are you using $x$ to designate $\times$?  I mean, are you trying to ask, e.g. whether $(\mathbb Z/5)^\times \cong (\mathbb Z/10)^\times$?

Comment: yes that is right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^{\times}=\{1,3,5,7\}$ any element $x$ verify $x^2=1$. But in $(\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z)^{\times}$, $3^2=9\neq 1$.